# Normalize a serialized table

Tags: php, mysql, normalization

I have the following tables used for sending messages about products to vendors from companies:

```
Table Messages:
INT PK  Message_ID 
TEXT    Message
INT FK  Company_ID
INT FK  Product_ID
DATE    Date
TEXT    Message_Receivers
TEXT    Email_Attachments
TINYINT Status

Table Email_addresses:
INT PK  Company_Email_ID
INT FK  Company_ID
VARCHAR Email_Name
VARCHAR Email_Address

Table Attachments:
INT PK  attachment_id
INT FK  image_id
INT FK  product_id
DATE    Upload_date
VARCHAR Category
```

Right now, if a message is sent to multiple recievers and if it has multiple attachments they are put into the messages table serialized. I am not that familiar with this method and would like to normalize the tables so that there is a reciever and an attachment on one row but I'm not seeing how to do so.

My question is, is there a benefit to leaving it serialized? As a newbie I'm unsure if I'm missing a benefit and if normalization is the key can you give me a hint on how to do so?

Comment: Okay, so continuing my search I found this article which leads me to believe that serialization in general is not the way to go when you have normalization in mind. [Normalization vs Serialization](http://tech.fireflake.com/2009/04/30/php-serialize-vs-database-normalization/)

Comment: I suppose the determining factor really is the sort of operations you will be doing with this data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IMHO, Normalization is always the first assumption.  The serialization is very good for programmatic use, but is completely counter-productive to anything that MySQL might ever be involved in.  My general approach is to serialize things like user settings, perhaps some transactional history, and things like that - stuff that I know will never be included in a SQL statement.

While search response times are, and should always be, important considerations, many folks seem to miss the fact the DB engines are designed for searching, so as long as you're following normalization rules with your DB design, then searching for data that is meant to be searchable should always run fine.